# Как поставить иконки перед item?

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Возникла проблема с иконками их нужно разместить перед заголовком. И не могу никак понять, что я сделал неправильно.

```
school__item {
  width: 350px;
  margin-right: 75px;
  position: relative;
  
}
.school__item::before{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}

.school__item--accommodation::before{
     background-image: url('../images/sun-icon.svg');
}
.school__item--fly::before{
     background-image: url('../images/airplane-icon.svg');
}
.school__item--learn::before{
     bac[![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1]kground-image: url('../images/surfer-icon.svg');
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `.school__item { padding-left: 50px; }`?

Comment: В каком-то смысле помогло, спасибо

Comment: html разметка уже не правильная, зачем стилями иконки грузить? а если они вдруг поменять захотят их?

Comment: @ЕвгенийЛи `html разметка уже не правильная` HTML'а как такового не предоставлено. `зачем стилями иконки грузить? а если они вдруг поменять захотят их?` - Просто поменять их?...

Comment: @ΝNL993 РЕЬД нет, но по стилям можно понять, что не правильно верстает. Просто поменять их? А кто будет менять иконки? Вы будете менять, когда клиент, которому вы сдадите проект попросит вас? А если он будет каждый день просить вас поменять иконки? А если год пройдёт и он должен вас найти, что бы вы поменяли ему иконки? Клиент должен вносить изменения через админку, а для этого нужно выводить изображения через HTML!

Comment: @ЕвгенийЛи ну не знаю :/, проект больше похож на какой-то лендинг чем на тот которому нужна админка.

Comment: Пусть это будет хоть Лэндинг в котором вы объясните клиенту, где можно поменять изображение или какой либо текст - это будет HTML файл. Ни разу не видел, что бы объясняли клиенту, что нужно зайти в стили и там менять. Тем более, если стили скомпилированы, попробуй поменять что-то в этом css.

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так

```css
.school__item {
  width: 350px;
  margin-right: 75px;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.school__title-wrapper {
  width: 90%;
  display: flex;
  gap: 30px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.school__image {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  display: block;
  background: #000;
}
.school__title {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 18px;
}
.description {
  text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<div class="school__item">
  <div class="school__title-wrapper">
    <img class="school__image" src"/" alt="school__image">
    <span class="school__title">Каой-то текст</span>
  </div>
  <div class="description">Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для текстов на латинице с начала XVI века. В то время некий безымянный печатник создал большую коллекцию размеров и форм шрифтов, используя Lorem Ipsum для распечатки образцов</div>
</div>
```